# Async function in next

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios, next.js

Good day!
I want to send client ip from frontend in next.js to backend

For get ip i use this function:

```
    async function getip() {
        var c = await publicIp.v4();
        return c;
    }
    export default getip;
```

and send with axios post.

```
    getip().then(ip => {
       axios.post('/, {

                body: ip

            }). then((res) => {}...}
```

server show ip in console but

```
var IP = req.body;
  console.log(IP); // ***undefined***
```

Comment: Is it `function getip() {` or  is it `async function ip() {`? As posted, that's a syntax error.

Comment: Most likely, `ip` is a promise. You need to wait for the result before sending the request.

Comment: What is `publicIp.v4();`? What is that "next" framework you talk about (the tag looks wrong)? Why would you send the client IP address in the body of a request? Just send an empty request, the backend receives the IP of the request sender anyway.

Comment: Next.js. I have 2 pages. From index.js i call funciton getip(), which include async funciton ip(){}.

Comment: Well, "including" the function is not enough. You need to actually call it and return its promise. Please post the full, actual code of `getip`.

Answer (score 0):

so the thing is that you are expecting a string probably but an async function gives you a promise of a string which is as the name implies just a promise.

If and when that promise is resolved only then you can use the contained data.

```js
function getIpSomehow() {
  return new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          res("127.0.0.1")
        },500)}
      )
  }
  async function getIp() {
    //var c = await publicIp.v4();
    const c = await getIpSomehow();
    return c;
  }

  getIp().then(ip => {
    //all axios stuff in here
    console.log(ip)
  })
  //however as you may see getIp function is quite useless so we could as well do 
  // getIpSomehow().then(...)
```

Comment: Yes, it work. should add async call function getIp().then(..... Thank you!
in server req.body show IP.
But when try to equate 
var IP = req.body
console.log(IP); // undefined
is any way to take ip value?

Comment: req.body is an object you should get the ip using the key you specified such as const IP = req.body.whateverYouSetHereInTheReq;